# Move "Select your language" to top of page on careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, internationalization

The language selection on careers is not visible until you scroll to the bottom of the page.  Our hiring group in Ensisheim, FR could not understand a listing until they realized if they scroll to the bottom they could click their flag and see the text in their language.

[image]

It would be helpful to move this to the top of the careers page and make it a dropdown?

Comment: Did you intend for this to be a feature request? Or just discussion?

Comment: Well I'm not sure if this is really that important for the SE developers to do something right away.  My point was looking at it from the user's perspective it isn't obvious.  Most multi-lingual sites have the flags or language selection at the top so its noticeable and easily changed.

Comment: Fair suggestion, I would like to see it added to the top bar as a drop down list, this way it's not changing the current design.

Answer (score 1):

**JonH**, a few months ago we updated our language selector. The idea you mentioned was definitely talked about yet there were a few problems that made that option less than ideal for us. Selecting a language isn't primary or secondary task for most users. Putting a language selector in the top bar though visually raises it to that level. We're wary of placing navigation and tools in the top bar area that will go largely ignored by most people. This could create some "bar blindness" now that could impede adoption of other future tools or links.

Our current implementation attempts to detect user's physical location by their IP address and redirect the user to a language if they fall into an area we've designated belonging to a translation we support. If we don't detect them falling within any of our designated translation areas, then we serve the default English (US) translation. This isn't a fool-proof implementation, but it's a solid first step. The links in the footer are the fallback options.